# Why is using wp_mail() with sendgrid api key setup not showing "via Sendgrid.com" at the sender name?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, smtp, sendgrid

I noticed that when I use a library in nodejs or a plugin in wordpress, the sent email will have a sender section that look like this "name<example@gmail.com> via <smtp service name>". What does the "via <service name domain>" try to tell us, and why I can't not see it when using the same api key but using wp_mail() function.
[image]

```
define( 'SMTP_USERNAME', 'apikey' );
define( 'SMTP_PASSWORD', 'SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' );  
define( 'SMTP_SERVER', 'smtp.sendgrid.net' );   
define( 'SMTP_FROM', 'xxxx@yyy.zzz' );
define( 'SMTP_NAME', 'abc' );  
define( 'SMTP_PORT', '587' );    
define( 'SMTP_SECURE', 'tls' );  
define( 'SMTP_AUTH', true );  
define( 'SMTP_DEBUG',   0 );
```

This is the config I used for both.

Comment: Checkout [Domain Authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication)

Comment: Please link to the respective Node.js library and WordPress plugin. It's impossible to know without having access to the relevant code.